# How is it that Borkul the Beast is a Forsworn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How is it that Borkul the Beast is a Forsworn?  There are two Orc strongholds in or near the Reach, but how does an Orc fall in with the Forsworn?  Is there an in-game explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think he's actually a forsworn... or at least, he wasn't until he got into Cidhna Mine. If you talk to him about his prison time, he answers:

> Guards brought me in about 12 years ago. Was running a good group of
>   bandits up until then. But these Forsworn. They're nothing like the
>   men I cobbled together. They're real killers

The way he says *they* instead of *us*, suggest that he's not one of them... he's just Madanach's bodyguard.

If you release the prisoners, he will join them in Druadach Redoubt, *to start his life anew as a part of the forsworn*, according to [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Borkul_the_Beast)